# Handling promise errors in chain, am I too eager?

Tags: javascript, promise

Fairly new to angular and promises in general and I felt like I was doing everything right, until I read about common promise anti-patterns. I also noticed my code was getting really difficult to follow and read.

BTW, using Angular's Q implementation.

In this chain, am I handling error correctly? Should I use catch instead? How would I do that? Can I make my code more succinct?

EDIT:
Couldn't find a question that talked about how to handle conditional promises. All the other stackoverflow questions were very simple without any complex chaining like my example. Hope this question helps someone

```
function importantPromise(){
    var deferred = $q.defer();
    var importantVariable;

    topLevelPromise().then(function(result) {
        var secondResult = doSomeWork(result, importantVariable);
        secondPromise(secondResult)
            .then(function(result) {
                deferred.resolve(result);
            }, function(error) {
                deferred.reject(error);
            });
    }, function(error) {
        conditionalPromise(importantVariable)
            .then(function(result) {
                deferred.resolve(result);
            }, function(error) {
                deferred.reject(error);
            });
    });
    return deferred.promise;
}

//Actually using the promise
importantPromise().then(function(result){
    handleResult(result);
}, function(error){
    handleError(error);
});
```

Comment: You shouldn't be using deferreds at all.  Instead, return promises to build a chain.

Comment: But the promises depends on the previous promise? If I return the final promise won't I be losing the chance to handle the error of the `topLevelPromise()` ?

Comment: `return secondFunction().then(function() { return result; })`

Comment: Interesting, maybe what I'm confused about is what happens to the error of what you wrote? 
Does it get bubbled up if I don't specify the second argument of `then()` ?

Comment: Yes; if you don't specify an error handler, errors are returned as-is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Funny, I just sent out an email to my team about exactly this mistake.  You are making things far too hard for yourself.  Just do this:

```
function importantPromise(){
    var importantVariable;

    return topLevelPromise().then(function(result) {
      var secondResult = doSomeWork(result, importantVariable);
      return secondPromise(secondResult);
    }).catch(function(error) {
      return conditionalPromise(importantVariable);
    });
}
```

This is the essence of promise-chaining.

You are probably thinking, "No, if I do this, my handleResult and handleError functions will get called prematurely, with promises instead of final values!"

No, no, no, porpoise-puss.  Promise-chaining means that if a resolution function returns a promise, that promise is itself resolved and its value is passed to the next resolution-function in the chain.  Try it.

Comment: Wow, that was defiantly the missing piece, thank you sir!

Comment: oops, first time doing this, thanks

Comment: @Malvolio: But [that's not the same](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24663315/1048572)! I think OP did use the pattern on purpose.

Comment: @Bergi, it cannot be the same: it's better!  The previous version would only catch errors in `topLevelPromise()`; this version also catches any problems with `secondPromise()`.  Bizarrely, as I noted I was talking to my team about the original issue yesterday, then today, 10 minutes after I read that blog post, I had exactly that problem in my code (an exception in the success handler not being caught).

Comment: It seems to me that the intention was to execute `conditionalPromise(…)` only if `topLevelPromise()` failed - not always we want to just catch all exceptions, but actually handle specific errors.

Comment: In that case, I think (but am not sure) that you use the `.then(fulfill, reject)` form.  All the other structures I can think of, either `conditionalPromise()` would receive errors from `secondPromise()` or `secondPromise()` would receive output from `conditionalPromise()`.

Comment: @Bergi @Malvolio I had done the original code to catch all the errors. At least that was my intention. Having looked up more on this subject. I can't really see a situation where you would use `function(error)` over `.catch(error)`. Unless its some edge case where you want to  NOT catch the `throwables` in the success case. Am i thinking of it right?

Comment: This ticket is surreally tracking my life: this morning I had a problem where a 404-error (file not found) in one step in the middle of a 10-step-long chain of promises could be handled with a special intervention, but all other errors had to exit out to an logged warning.

Comment: @Malvolio, I've been playing around with both styles all morning and there is definitely a BIG distinction and not knowing the difference can be really bad. I just knocked out some bugs I couldn't explain in my code by revisiting it

Comment: `.catch(f)` is sugar for `.then(null, f)`.  The difference between `.then(g,f)` and `.then(g).catch(f)` is that the latter will _also_ get any errors from `g`.